# Animate seekbar progress

Tags: android, animation, seekbar

I have a screen with 4 seek bars ( As shown in the image below) . If the user moves B,C or D I calculate the average of the three and setProgress of A to the average. That was the easy part . What I would like to do is animate the progress bar A such that it does not jump in one shot (for eg from 25-75 ).

What are the recommended ways to animate A? I got a simple animation up but I am calling a TimerTask every 50ms to increment or decrement A by a unit value till I reach the required position. But its not very efficient.

Note: I have a custom Seekbar object using which I have created seekBar's A,B,C & D. Sorry I cant really share the code but will be happy to clarify anything.

[image]

Comment: the most important question is on which event you update the seekbars? I have a similar situation (3 bars with 0-100) and all three bars together should always be 100... works without "jumping" for me... so on which event does A get updated?

Comment: When ever either B,C or D is changed I recalculate the average of the 3 and set it as A's value. This is done only when the user just click the 3 seekBars and not when there is a continuous change.

Comment: ah ok, now I understand it...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I reduced the number of iterations by iterating the timer task over an exponential function instead of unit increments. Still hoping for better answers :-)

Answer (score 22):

I guess its too late. But I found a way to achieve this using ValueAnimator.

```
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, seekBar.getMax());
anim.setDuration(1000);
anim.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
    int animProgress = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
    seekBar.setProgress(animProgress);
    }
});
anim.start();
```

Comment: Why not use `ObjectAnimator`?

Answer (score 6):

I have done it using `ObjectAnimator`.

```
private void animateProgression(int progress) {
    final ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mySeekBar, "progress", 0, progress);
    animation.setDuration(3000);
    animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animation.start();
    mySeekBar.clearAnimation();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works on any Android version, without using any animations.

```
private void animateSeek(final SeekBar mSeek, final int toVal) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (true) {
                if (mSeek.getProgress() == toVal) {
                    break;
                }
                int mProgress = mSeek.getProgress();
                if (mProgress < toVal) {
                    mProgress++;

                } else if (mProgress > toVal) {
                    mProgress--;
                }

                mSeek.setProgress(mProgress);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed code that was just like what @sidhanshu_udawat had done.
That was a great base to start from. Big win because it runs on its own thread. Thanks for that example.

However, when I took that code and tried it there was an issue that it would increment up and then stop.

I altered the code (pasted below) and now if you send in your seekbar with code like the following you will see that the seekbar animates up and down the scale.

**isRunning - Control From Your Activity**

Also, I needed to stop the animation when someone clicked a button so I added the boolean isRunning as a member on my Activity.  Now when they click the button, I set isRunnig to false and the SeekBar stops.

Set up your SeekBar like the following and then call the method:

```
animSeekBar.incrementProgressBy(1);
  animSeekBar.setMax(100);
  animateSeek(animSeekBar,100);

private void animateSeek(final SeekBar mSeek, final int toVal) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                boolean isIncrementing = true;
                int mProgress = 0;
                isRunning = true;

                while (isRunning) {
                    if (isIncrementing){
                        mProgress++;
                    }
                    else{
                        mProgress--;
                    }
                    mSeek.setProgress(mProgress);
                    if (mProgress >= toVal) {
                        isIncrementing = false;

                    } else if (mProgress <= 0) {
                        isIncrementing = true;
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Honeycomb then you can use ViewPropertyAnimator 
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-viewpropertyanimator.html

The animation before 3.0 is quite limited but as an alternative to your method you could use an animation listener:

```
anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
  public void onAnimationStart(Animation anim) {
     //moveseekbar
  }
  public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation anim) {}
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim) {
     //call animation again if movement not complete
  }
});
```

Don't forget to call setFillAfter(boolean fillAfter)
because the animation <3.0 doesn't actually move the view. It just gives the illusion that the view has moved. Important distinction if you still want the seekbar to continue to receive touches.

Comment: Which Animation would I use here?